# Converting dd-mm-yyyy string to date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, date-format

I am passing a date in string format `11-09-2013` in `dd-mm-yyyy` format from JSP. My query is:

```
select convert(varchar(10),'11-09-2013',106)
```

But it is not giving my expected output, which is:

```
11-SEP-2013
```

Comment: Why don't you pass a standard format like yyyymmdd from JSP? Or just pass a date instead of a string???

Comment: best to avoid `dd-mm-yyyy` format and go for the much more universal `yyyymmdd`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @d CHAR(10) = '11-09-2013'; -- dd-mm-yyyy

SELECT UPPER(REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(11), CONVERT(DATETIME, @d, 103), 106), ' ', '-'));

-- if 2008+ you can use DATE instead:
SELECT UPPER(REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(11), CONVERT(DATE, @d, 103), 106), ' ', '-'));

-- if 2012 you can use:
SELECT UPPER(FORMAT(CONVERT(DATE, @d, 103), 'dd-MMM-yyyy'));
```

Result in all three cases:

```
11-SEP-2013
```

However, this can be very expensive to convert to strings etc. like this. Why do you need this output format, and where is it going? If this is being presented at the client you are much better off using the string formatting capabilities at the client.